# SAS: Need to optimize for Z. Please Fix it

Tags: sas, statistics, nonlinear-optimization

The problem is, when ran this code is not giving results. I am learning but not able to comprehend where it is wrong. 
The statement is: Vans that can operate on the routes(dc to shelter) are in short supply, so we want to choose the location of the DC (from DC1 to DC5) to minimize the transport work (total kit-miles travelled) in the network. Note that transport work per kit is proportional to distance. The supply and demand are in no of kits. distance matrix` is in miles.

Which of the location out of the five locations of DC should we choose to minimize the transport work in the network?

```
proc optmodel;

set shelter={"S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8"};
set dc={"D1", "D2","D3","D4", "D5"};

number demand{shelter}=[14000 8000 25000 22000 20000 17000 18500 23000];
number supply{dc}=[150000 150000 150000 150000 150000];

number distance{dc,shelter}=[
0.61 3.32 9.5 6.52 7.77 1.92 8.52 9.75
6.04 0.51 1.34 6.06 0.22 6.33 4.61 3.28
4.99 2.41 2.33 3.95 8.84 7.94 7.87 0.94
5.58 8.8 6.32 8.54 5.15 6.06 9.42 2.16
7.87 9.64 0.7 5.92 2.7 0.26 0.5 3.4];

number C=1;

var x{dc, shelter} integer>=0;
var b{dc} binary;

minimize Z=sum{d in dc, s in shelter} (x[d,s]*C*distance[d,s]*300000*b[d]);

con demandcon{s in shelter}:sum{d in dc} x[d,s]=demand[s];
con supplycon{d in dc}:sum{s in shelter} x[d,s]<=supply[d];
con bincon:sum{d in dc} b[d]<=5;
con bincon2:sum{d in dc} b[d]>=1;
con bindingcon{d in dc}: sum{s in shelter} x[d,s] <= b[d]*10000000;

solve;

print Z b x;

quit;
```

log

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 70         
 71         proc optmodel;
 72         
 73         set shelter={"S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8"};
 74         set dc={"D1", "D2","D3","D4", "D5"};
 75         
 76         number demand{shelter}=[14000 8000 25000 22000 20000 17000 18500 23000];
 77         number supply{dc}=[150000 150000 150000 150000 150000];
 78         
 79         number distance{dc,shelter}=[
 80         0.61 3.32 9.5 6.52 7.771.92 8.52 9.75
 81         6.04 0.51 1.34 6.06 0.22 6.33 4.61 3.28
 82         4.99 2.41 2.33 3.95 8.84 7.94 7.87 0.94
 83         5.58 8.8 6.32 8.54 5.15 6.06 9.42 2.16
 84         7.87 9.64 0.7 5.92 2.7 0.260.5 3.4];
 85         
 86         number C=1;
 87         
 88         var x{dc, shelter} integer>=0;
 89         var b{dc} binary;
 90         
 91         minimize Z=sum{d in dc, s in shelter} (x[d,s]*C*distance[d,s]*300000*b[d]);
 92         
 93         con demandcon{s in shelter}:sum{d in dc} x[d,s]=demand[s];
 94         con supplycon{d in dc}:sum{s in shelter} x[d,s]<=supply[d];
 95         con bincon:sum{d in dc} b[d]<=5;
 96         con bincon2:sum{d in dc} b[d]>=1;
 97         con bindingcon{d in dc}: sum{s in shelter} x[d,s] <= b[d]*10000000;
 98         
 99         solve;
 NOTE: Problem generation will use 2 threads.
 NOTE: The problem has 45 variables (0 free, 0 fixed).
 NOTE: The problem has 5 binary and 40 integer variables.
 NOTE: The problem has 20 linear constraints (11 LE, 8 EQ, 1 GE, 0 range).
 NOTE: The problem has 135 linear constraint coefficients.
 NOTE: The problem has 0 nonlinear constraints (0 LE, 0 EQ, 0 GE, 0 range).
 NOTE: The OPTMODEL presolver removed 0 variables, 6 linear constraints, and 0 nonlinear constraints.
 NOTE: The OPTMODEL presolved problem has 45 variables, 14 linear constraints, and 0 nonlinear constraints.
 NOTE: The OPTMODEL presolver removed 45 linear constraint coefficients, leaving 90.
 ERROR: The QP solver does not allow integer variables.
 100        
 101        print Z b x;
 102        
 103        quit;
 NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTMODEL used (Total process time):
       real time           0.05 seconds
       user cpu time       0.05 seconds
       system cpu time     0.00 seconds
       memory              2377.03k
       OS Memory           28836.00k
       Timestamp           04/17/2018 05:13:19 PM
       Step Count                        119  Switch Count  3
       Page Faults                       0
       Page Reclaims                     565
       Page Swaps                        0
       Voluntary Context Switches        27
       Involuntary Context Switches      1
       Block Input Operations            0
       Block Output Operations           344


 104        
 105        OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 117
```

Comment: Include your log and the errors generated.

Comment: Thank you for asking, just did.

Comment: You will need to reformulate your problem to be linear. You are multiplying two variables, x and b, together; however, you are requesting integer constraints. You can reformulate your objective function using a Big M method: 
https://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/Nonlinear-Mix-Integer-Optimization/td-p/327900

Comment: Folks please remember to use comments for clarifying, but the answer section for answering the question.